# Lagom: Asynchronous Operations in Command Handlers

Tags: scala, asynchronous, persist, lagom

In Lagom, what do you do when a command handler must perform some asynchronous operations? For example:

```
override def behavior = Actions().onCommand[MyCommand, Done] {
  case (cmd, ctx, state) =>
    // some complex code that performs asynchronous operations
    // (for example, querying other persistent entities or the read-side
    // by making calls that return Future[...] and composing those),
    // as summarized in a placeholder below:
    val events: Future[Seq[Event]] = ???
    events map {
      xs => ctx.thenPersistAll(xs: _*) { () => ctx.reply(Done) }
    }
}
```

The problem with the code like that is that the compiler expects the command handler to return `Persist`, not `Future[Persist]`.

Is this done on purpose, to make sure that the events are persisted in the correct order (that is, the events generated by a prior command must be saved before the events generated by a later command)? But can't that be handled by proper management of the event offsets, so that the journal always orders them correctly, regardless of when they are actually saved?

And what does one do in situations like this, when the command handling is complex enough to require making asynchronous calls from the command handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar question on the mailing list with an answer from James. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/lagom-framework/Z6lynjNTqgE

In short, your entity in a CQRS application is a consistency boundary and should only depend on data that it's immediately available inside it, not outside (no call to external services).

What you are probably looking for a what it's called `Command Enrichment`. You receive an request, collect some data from external services and build a command containing everything you need to send to your Entity.

You certainly should not query the read-side to make business decisions inside your write-side entity. You also should not make business decisions on data coming from other entities.

Your entity should be able to make all the decision because it is the consistency boundary of your model.

Comment: This is all fine and well, but when one aggregate can reference entities inside another aggregate (and generically!), the consistency boundary for delete cascades becomes the entire world. Unless, of course, deletion is disabled entirely, which may be an option.

Comment: I guess I can do preDelete to collect all entities preventing deletion or all entities that must be also deleted/updated through cascades, and only then actually issue the commands to perform those actions.

Comment: I don't know if I get your point about `preDelete`, but keep in mind the following:

Aggregate design is quite different than old-style traditional CRUD modelling. Make sure you understand that before starting.

First, you don't manipulate entities leaving inside another aggregate from outside it. You can reference than, but only the aggregate owing them is allowed to change them. 

Also, consistency boundary does not move unless you refactor your model. There is no such a thing as: in this context I will make a larger boundary. Your consistency boundary is your domain, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, yes, of course. Any cascade going outside the aggregate prevents the delete. But we still need to know it exists, and we need to generate the cascades inside the aggregate. So we need to query the information on which entities link to which other entities, and in which aggregates.

Comment: And even though it is possible to look just inside a given aggregate to search for its own entities linking to each other, one still has to find out which links cascade to delete, which cascade to update, and which prevent the operation. This information is stored in a schema aggregate, which the given aggregate references, so there is a Future operation to obtain it, anyway.

Comment: Oh, and we need links from outside the given aggregate, of course. Anyway, command enrichment works. I have already implemented it. Thanks!

Comment: @silverberry all those links you mention, delete cascading and looking inside the state of the aggregate is totally extraneous to CQRS. You are seeing it as a bunch of relations crossing boundaries. Don't get me wrong, but if you talk on those terms it means that you are working on CRUD model and trying to force it inside an Aggregate concept. That simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let me try to explain it in another way. Your Aggregate is a isolated, fully autonomous model. You send Commands to it and it will emit Events that represents changes on that specific model. You have state, but it's purpose is to validate your Commands and decide which Events to emit. Nothing else. 
From the emitted events you, asynchronously, update views. There you are in a CRUD, destructive, world. You can make links between table or choose for a flat data structure (preferred).  But you don't navigate references to make decisions inside your Aggregate. It's all in there, nothing outside.

Comment: @silverberry I recommend you to go through this two resources and rethink your modelling. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx

 http://cqrs.nu/

The worst thing you can do is to mix CRUD and Aggregate design. Make sure you get the difference on that.

Comment: My apologies, but it would take too long to fully explain the domain model. Some of the language used here may sound like CRUD, but it is actually not.

Comment: No worries. I just hope it was useful for you. Otherwise, you can reach out to the mailing list. It's easier to have such discussion there. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing in these cases is to pass the PersistentEntityRef to the asynchronous operation, so that it can issue commands to the entity and its those command-handlers (not the one that spawned the async computation) that then persist the events.

Just bear in mind that none of this is atomic, so you have to think about what happens if the asynchronous operation fails midway through issuing the commands or if some commands succeed and some fail, etc. Presumably you'll want some retry mechanism for systemic failures. If you build your command-handlers to be idempotent, it will help you deal with the duplicates.